# Can multiple battle.net account have the same email address?

Tags: battle.net

Can multiple battle.net account have the same email address?

My friend is giving me his account but I already have one, and I know you can't merge non WOW games. Can I change his email address to the same one as mine?

Comment: I believe the answer is "why in the world is getting a second email address a problem". With email addresses being easily obtained for free, this seems to be unnecessarily complicated. (Also, I'm pretty sure that you can't have multiple accounts with the same address. It would make passwords resets impossible to do securely on Blizzard's end, for starters.)

Comment: Why don't you just try it? The Earth won't explode if you will try to change email address

Comment: Last time I come here, I figured the people on this site would be like stack overflow. I guess I am wrong.

Comment: I think it's best to ask Blizzard about merging accounts. They will have the authoritative answer on this. Once you've obtained your answer, you are most welcome to come back here and post it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 6):

No. Think about it. Since you have to use an email address to log in, how would the login server ever know what account to log you into?

You'll just need to create a new email address. Also, from Blizzard's Terms of Service:

> **Ownership/Selling of the Account or Virtual Items.**
>
> Blizzard does not recognize the transfer of Accounts. You may not purchase, sell, gift or trade any Account, or offer to purchase, sell, gift or trade any Account, and any such attempt shall be null and void. Blizzard owns, has licensed, or otherwise has rights to all of the content that appears in the Program. You agree that you have no right or title in or to any such content, including the virtual goods or currency appearing or originating in the Game, or any other attributes associated with the Account or stored on the Service. Blizzard does not recognize any virtual property transfers executed outside of the Game or the purported sale, gift or trade in the "real world" of anything related to the Game. Accordingly, you may not sell items for "real" money or otherwise exchange items for value outside of the Game.